# PHP 7.2 Challenge

Tags: php

We have a wordpress site that required a PHP 7.2 update. The update failed and our host provider said that it was most likely a plugin that we're using. We have about 15 plugins. What would be the best approach to finding out which plugin/s are not compatible with PHP 7.2?

Thanks!!
Tom

Comment: Switch to PHP 7.2, turn on WP_DEBUG and check which plugin causes errors.

Comment: By check, he means look in the error log, you can also use a tool such as PHPCompat. TBH though, this isn't really a WordPress question but a general PHP question, it might have been better asked on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

If you can install and run [`phpcs`](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) from the command line, you can try adding the PHPCompatibility library and running it to generate a report. [Examples](https://gist.github.com/MikeNGarrett/8847435182e460dac519dcda7e99eb3a) This will help identify potential issues.

If that's not possible, there's a plugin that will help check your site for PHP compatibility issues called the [PHP Compatibility Checker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-compatibility-checker/). It will do the same thing as above, but doesn't require running anything from the command line.